# Help with Installing linux kernel from source!

Tags: grub2, kernel

I am using Ubuntu Desktop and I am new to linux kernel development.
I am following the documentation https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/README.html#compiling-the-kernel 
And I am stuck at the "Compiling the kernel" section.

As far as I know Ubuntu uses GRUB by default but the instruction given are for LILO. So, I do not know what am I supposed to do next after successfully running the 
"sudo make O=/home/name/build/kernel modules_install install" command here
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/README.html#build-directory-for-the-kernel

Can someone explain in simple terms as I am relatively new to kernel development that what do I need to do next.
Thank you

Comment: the first part of linux from scratch will take you through that process.

Comment: The architecture being used will dictate if grub, or lilo is assumed default.  If building Ubuntu for s390 the default boot loader for example is zipl (very similar to lilo), you didn't however specify your intended architecture, which has a huge influence on boot loader.  (the kernel source isn't limited to amd64/x86*)